# Eval and Prompt complications

Tags: javascript, newline, eval, prompt

So I've been messing around with the eval function, and was working on a little chat project using prompt. If I do:

```
var test = 'prompt("Username: Jimbles \n Message:")'
eval(test)
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

This is because it's putting a new line in the string itself when it's evaluated, rather than putting it in the prompt.

Here's what JavaScript sees:

```
'prompt("Username: Jimbles 
Message:")'
```

I need to use eval since I'm getting the code to execute from a server, and need a way to execute it. How would I successfully be able to use newline in eval without getting this error and putting a newline in the eval string itself? I want there to be a newline in the prompt, but not the evaluated string. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want `test` to literally contain `\n`, you need to escape the backslash.

Ie:

```
var test = 'prompt("Username: Jimbles \\n Message:")'
eval(test)
```

Comment: Thanks, It works great! What exactly is "escaping" though?  It looks a bit like regEx to me

Comment: @Gorgamite Escape characters tell the program that the next character means something special. Eg `\n` means newline `\t` mean tab etc. Therefore if you actually want a backslash in your string, you need to use \\.

Comment: ah, I understand. So you're basically telling eval to take "\n" literally, as part of the string. Thanks!